# Prestashop change priority of CSS

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I am using prestashop 1.7.X and I have overridden the file ps_shoppingcart.less to give the shoppingcart a modified style. However these rules interfere with the file cart.styl.
Since I want to achieve compatibility with upcoming versions, I want to make the less file having a higher priority then the styl file so the rules don't interfere anymore. 
How can I do this and what would be the best practice to do this?
(I know that I could just delete the content of the styl file).
Rsgards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way is to use prestashop priority (on PS 1.7)

```
$this->context->controller->addCSS(css_path, 'all', priority);
```